# BigQuery Partition by Day( timestamp column ) is not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 1 partition on column `_installed_at_` (timestamp), see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgPCf.png). But when I run

```
SELECT * FROM `data-analytics-experiment.data_3rd_party.raw_adjust` WHERE DATE(_installed_at_) = "2022-05-31" LIMIT 1000
```

This query processed all the tables, the partition is not running. This query returned no results.
See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GW3h.png)

Help please T.T

Comment: Is the table name something like `raw_adjust_20220531` for the stuff that happened on the 31st of May?

Comment: This table named raw_adjust, contains all date( timestamp) data. I checked BigQuery partitioned but it did not work when I query like this. I also tested on other date partition tables, and it works

Comment: Would you try `WHERE _installed_at_ >= '2022-05-31' AND _installed_at < '2022-06-01'` without applying a function to a partition column ?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of how the dataset of that partitioned table looks like? If it is partitioned, it should follow the same naming convention for each partition. E.g. raw_adjust_2022-05-29, raw_adjust_2022-05-30, raw_adjust_2022-05-31

Comment: Type of `_installed_at_` is timestamp. I think must add DATE function. I tried your way, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @AleixCC Sceenshoot of partitions is [here](https://postimg.cc/9wywDkv7)

Comment: You mean you still get empty result or your query still full-scan your table ?

Comment: Could you also send a screenshot of how you see the different table names inside the schema? So directly from the BigQuery UI, as if you were to inspect the table itself.

Comment: Last updated date of your table is 30 May. (from your 1st screenshot).  It looks the reason you get an empty result is there is no data on 31 May. And the reason your query do full-scan your table without partition pruning is because you apply a function to a partitin column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below screenshot says that your table is partitioned but most values in `_installed_at_` which is a partition column are not valid.

You might want to check if `_installed_at_` is properly generated or parsed from string-formatted timestamp.

[image: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS]

Comment: The cause is column `_install_at_` has many null values. Thank you <3